# How to parallelize dot product with MPI_Scatter correctly?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, linear-algebra

Stack overflow! I'm writing a parallel computation program for term project in my university. I've tried to parallelize dot product with MPI:

```
double Multiply(double *X,double *Y,int N) {
    MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    MPI_Comm comm;
    double *Xbuffer;
    Xbuffer=new double[N/world_size];
    double *Ybuffer;
    Ybuffer=new double[N/world_size];
    double *curr;
    curr=new double[N/world_size];
    MPI_Scatter(X,N/world_size,MPI_DOUBLE,Xbuffer,1,MPI_DOUBLE,0,comm);
    MPI_Scatter(Y,N/world_size,MPI_DOUBLE,Ybuffer,1,MPI_DOUBLE,0,comm);
    for (int i=0;i<N/world_size;i++) curr[i]=Xbuffer[i]*Ybuffer[i];
    if (world_rank==0) {
        double *prods;
        prods=new double[N];
        MPI_Gather(curr,N/world_size,MPI_DOUBLE,prods,1,MPI_DOUBLE,0,comm);
        double Sum=0;
        for (int i=0;i<N;i++) Sum+=prods[i];
        return Sum;
    }
}
```

However, this code doesn't work, it shows me Segmentation fault in the result. As I understand, I can't scatter vectors into more pieces than I have processors to send them to, so I scatter them into N/world_size parts instead of N parts. What have I done wrong in this function?

Comment: `MPI_Gather()` is a collective subroutine and must hence be called by *all* ranks. `recvcount` is incorrect. That being said, your code is highly inefficient, and you'd rather compute the partial dot product on each rank, and then perform a parallel reduction to (directly) get the result.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, had a lot of other work to do. I had lots of other work to do. I changed MPI_Gather call and fixed recvcount.